# Is it possible to make a telnet connection between a client and a server on Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

I wanna capture telnet packet with such a simple client-server topology.

[image: A simple client-server topology]

There is no configuration under `Services` on the server-side.

I tried to telnet to the server on `Command Prompt` with:

```
C:\>telnet 192.168.1.80
Trying 192.168.1.80 ...
% Connection refused by remote host
```

I learned from serval guides that it is able to capture telnet packets by adding a switch or router.

My question is: is it possible to make a telnet connection on such a scenario: `client -- server`?

Comment: Packet Tracer is simply designed to get you through CCNA, and it lacks many features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes on a normal scenario but not in Packet tracer.

To be able to Jump to a Server using Telnet or SSH you should enable that telnet or SSH service on both client and server side. Packet tracer doesn't have that features on PCs and Servers i think...

To capture Telnet packets you could instead use a Router and as you said, a Switch to mirror ports.

**Something like this**

[image]

**Router Config**

[image]

[image]

**Switch Config**

[image]

On a real life scenario the Sniffer would be replaced by a PC or Laptop, and we would use a packet capture program like Wireshark.

I hope this is helpful, Regards!